# Otimizar consulta em banco de dados e compactar o código

Tags: delphi

Segue o código:

```
procedure TfrmGrid.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 txt: TextFile;
 treg, lreg: integer;
 valortxt, valorbd : double;
 dt1, dt2,lTemp, valor, dtcompratxt: String;
 dtcompra: TDateTime;
begin
lreg:= 1;
treg:= 0;

StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Abrindo arquivo de txt';
AssignFile(txt, frmSelection.FileListBox1.FileName);
Reset(txt);
 while not eof(txt) do
 begin
   Readln(txt, lTemp);
   if  (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E14') then
   begin
     StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Executando a query';
     dtcompratxt := copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,59,4);

     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT dtcompra, numnf, numcupom, ccf, valor FROM tdcupant');
     //DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE dtcompra BETWEEN '+dt1+' AND '+dt2+';');
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;
     DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.SetProvider(DModuleGrid.DataSetProvider1);
     DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.Open;

     if not (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.IsEmpty) then
     begin
       StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Executando o loop de consulta/comparação';
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.First;
       while not DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Eof do
       begin
         if (copy(lTemp,53,6) = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString)
         and (copy(lTemp,47,6) = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('ccf').AsString)
         and (StrToDateTime(dtcompratxt) = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('dtcompra').AsDateTime)
         or (copy(lTemp,4,20) = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numnf').AsString)
         then
         begin
          StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Incrementando registros';
          inc(lreg);
          //Valor no BD
          valorbd := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsFloat;
          //Valor no TXT
          valortxt := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100;
          //Diferença nos valores
          if (valorbd <> valortxt) then
          begin
           inc(treg);
           if (valor = '') then
           begin
            valor := IntToStr(0);
           end
           else
            valor := IntToStr(treg);
            Label1.Caption:='Divergências Cupons: '+valor;
          end;

         end;
         StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Próximo registro';
         DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Next;
       end;
     end;
   end;
   ProgressBar1.Position := ProgressBar1.Position+treg;
 end;
  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Existem '+ IntToStr(lreg) + ' linhas de Cupons(E14)';
  CloseFile(txt);
  CloseQuery;
end;
```

Como posso fazer com que o código fique mais compacto e consequentemente mais rápido?
Quando eu efetuo esta consulta, e ele vai buscar e comparar os valores no banco de dados, demora cerca de 5~6mins para retornar a trabalhar normalmente.

Alguem tem alguma idéia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Já tentou rodar a(s) consulta(s) no banco de dados por fora do programa? Se o gargalo estiver lá, pode ser mais importante otimizar a base (criando um índice, por exemplo) do que mexer no código.

Comment: Mas o código para vc esta correto? Ou tem como melhorar?

Comment: Eu não manjo de Delphi, só dei uma sugestão para evitar de você perder um tempão otimizando código para depois descobrir que era só criar um índice. rs

Comment: hahaha, entendi, mas me explica direitinho, um índice? (Desculpe-me a ignorância.) rsrs

Comment: Índices são objetos no banco de dados que agilizam a busca de registros em tabelas. Mas para saber se isso vai ajudar, é importante ver onde que está demorando, se é no acesso ao banco ou no processamento do código Delphi mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação @Dang, vou pesquisar sobre isso, saber aonde é problema da lentidão.

Comment: Estou terminando a resposta, posto daqui a pouco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Problema do seu código é que para cada linha do arquivo texto você está carregando todos os registros do banco. Eu fiz uma refatoração para ficar mais fácil de entender e ficou assim:

```
procedure TfrmGrid.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    CarregarDados;
end;

procedure PrepararQuery;
begin
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT dtcompra, numnf, numcupom, ccf, valor FROM tdcupant WHERE numnf = :numnf AND ccf = :ccf and numcupom = :numcupom');
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Prepare;    
end;

function EhLinhaCupom(const Linha: string): boolean;
begin
    Result := (copy(Linha, 1, 3) = 'E14');
end;

procedure AbrirQuery(const NumNf, CCF, NumCumpom: string);
begin
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('NumNf').AsString := NumNf;
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('CCF').AsString := CCF;
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('NumCumpom').AsString := NumCumpom;
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;

    //Não entendi a necessidade deste dataset
    DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.SetProvider(DModuleGrid.DataSetProvider1);
    DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.Open;    
end;

procedure ProcessaLinha(const Linha: string; var TotalDivergencia: integer);
var
    NumCupom, CCF, NumNF: string
    dtCompra: TDateTime;
    valorbd, valortxt: Currency;
begin
    if not EhLinhaCupom(Linha) then
        Exit;

    NumCupom := copy(lTemp,53,6);
    CCF := copy(lTemp,47,6);
    NumNF := copy(lTemp,4,20);
    dtCompra := StrToDate(copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,59,4));

    AbrirQuery(NumNf, CCF, NumCumpom);
    if DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.IsEmpty then
        Exit;

    StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Incrementando registros';
    inc(lreg);

    valorbd := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsFloat;
    valortxt := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100;

    //Diferença nos valores
    if (valorbd <> valortxt) then
    begin
        inc(TotalDivergencia);
        Label1.Caption:='Divergências Cupons: ' + IntToStr(TotalDivergencia);
    end;

    StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Próximo registro';
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Next;   
end;

procedure CarregarDados;
var
 txt: TextFile;
 TotalDivergencia, lreg: integer;
 lTemp: string;
begin
    PrepararQuery;
    lreg:= 0;   
    TotalDivergencia := 0;

    StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Abrindo arquivo de txt';
    AssignFile(txt, frmSelection.FileListBox1.FileName);
    try
        Reset(txt);
        while not eof(txt) do
        begin
            Readln(txt, lTemp); 
            ProcessaLinha(lTemp, TotalDivergencia);
            Inc(lreg);
            StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Próximo registro';
        end;

        StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Existem '+ IntToStr(lreg) + ' linhas de Cupons(E14)';
    finally     
        CloseFile(txt); 
    end;
end;
```

Mas um resultado melhor pode ser conseguido se você mudar o open da Query para fora do while e localizar os registros com um comando de locate na query

Comment: sua resposta foi muito útil, tirou umas dúvidas minhas, agora eu só nao consegui rodar, por causa dos parametros da base de dados, ele apresenta apenas nada no meu DBGrid.Como resolver?

Comment: @RamonRuan tente usar os parâmetros como Integer e usar um trim ao atribuir. Provavelmente está fazendo a query com os espaços do arquivo texto ou com os zeros à esquerda

Comment: mas se usar o StrToInt(), ele tbm não eliminará os zeros?

Comment: @RamonRuan Poste a estrutura da sua tabela e formato dos campos e algumas linhas da tabela e do arquivo texto como exemplo de dados. Aí veremos a melhor forma de montar os parametros da query

Comment: não poderia ser retirado os zeros, nesse caso, os zeros tbm contam, pois são 6 caracteres que pegam do arquivo txt. Mas vou postar o seu código que adaptei para o meu sitema, e vou tentar explicar brevemente como funciona ok?

Comment: @RamonRuan Você precisa fazer com que o valor passado para o parâmetro fique igual ao conteúdo do banco de dados

Comment: Meu amigo, deu certo a comparação, agora tenho que mostrar é as divergências no DBGrid :(, muito obrigado, por sinal, seu post ajudou muito :)