# Comparação funciona, mas listagem de dados não

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TfrmGrid.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 txt: TextFile;
 treg, lreg, dc: integer;
 valortxt, valorbd : double;
 dt1, dt2,lTemp, valor, dtcompratxt, numnf, coo,ccf: String;
 dtcompra: TDateTime;
begin
lreg:= 1;
treg:= 0;
dc := 0;
StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Abrindo arquivo de txt';
AssignFile(txt, frmSelection.FileListBox1.FileName);
Reset(txt);

 while not eof(txt) do
 begin
   Readln(txt, lTemp);
   if  (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E14') then
   begin
     StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Executando a query';
     dtcompra:=StrToDate(copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,59,4));
     dtcompratxt:= FormatDateTime('dd/MM/yyyy', dtcompra);

     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT dtcompra, impcaixa, numcupom, ccf, valor FROM tdcupant');
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE numcupom = :co2 AND ccf = :cc3 AND dtcompra = :dtc4 AND impcaixa = :ip5');
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('co2').AsString := copy(lTemp,53,6);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('cc3').AsString := copy(lTemp,47,6);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('ip5').AsString := copy(lTemp,4,20);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtc4').AsDate := StrToDate(dtcompratxt);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;

     if not (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.IsEmpty) then
     begin
       StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Executando o loop de consulta/comparação';
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.First;
         if  (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('co2').AsString)
         and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('ccf').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('cc3').AsString)
         and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('dtcompra').AsDateTime = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtc4').AsDate)
         and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('impcaixa').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('ip5').AsString)
         then
         begin
          StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Incrementando registros';
          inc(lreg);
          //Valor no BD
          valorbd := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsFloat;
          //Valor no TXT
          valortxt := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100;
          //Diferença nos valores
          if (valorbd <> valortxt) then
           begin
            inc(treg);
            if (valor = '') then
             begin
              valor := IntToStr(0);
             end
             else
             valor := IntToStr(treg);
           end;
         end
         else
         begin
         inc(dc);

         StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Próximo registro';
         end;
         DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Next;
     end;
   end;
 end;
  Label1.Caption := 'Divergências '+'Valor'+' Cupons: '+valor;
  Label7.Caption := 'Divergência de cupons: '+ IntToStr(dc);
  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Existem '+ IntToStr(lreg) + ' linhas de Cupons(E14)';
  CloseFile(txt);
end;
```

[Otimizar consulta em banco de dados e compactar o código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15713/otimizar-consulta-em-banco-de-dados-e-compactar-o-codigo/15729?noredirect=1#comment28759_15729)

O contexto da pergunta esta nos comentários, mas irei deixar claro.

O que tentei fazer foi uma comparação de um arquivo .txt com os dados contidos no DB.
Eu consegui fazer a comparação com este código, lembrando, o código funciona para a comparação, mas não esta funcionando para a listagem de dados em Outro DBGrid.

Ele esta utilizando o DBGrid apenas para a comparação e não para a listagem.
Alguma idéia?

Comment: O ping `@usuario` só funciona dentro dos Comentários para pessoas envolvidas no post (autor da pergunta, comentaristas, editores). Cada Pergunta deve ser auto-suficiente dando possibilidade a que qualquer um responda. Por favor, adicione detalhes que expliquem melhor seu problema.

Comment: @RamonRuan Se esta pergunta é baseada em outra, por favor coloque o link para entendermos o contexto.

Comment: @Andrey, Segue o link e uma explicação breve do que fiz, descupem o erro. Obrigado, espero que possam me ajudar.

Comment: @Crood, Sei sim cara... kkk, é por que o seguinte, o problema é que a seleção estava vindo com a cláusula WHERE e com parâmetros, consequentemente estava apenas comparando os dados, não tinha nenhuma função de seleção pura. VOu postar o código para vocês entenderem melhor

Comment: @Crood, haha, verdade, só consegui terminar depois de allmoçar, mas taí abaixo. por favor dê uma olhada. ;]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o código senhores:

```
procedure TfrmGrid.btnLoadCupClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 txt: TextFile;
 treg, lreg, dc: integer;
 valortxt, valorbd : double;
 lTemp, valor, dtcompratxt, ccf, coo, ecf: String;
 dtcompra, dtc: TDateTime;
begin
lreg:= 1;
treg:= 0;
dc := 0;

StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Abrindo arquivo de txt';
AssignFile(txt, frmSelection.FileListBox1.FileName);
Reset(txt);

 while not eof(txt) do
 begin
   Readln(txt, lTemp);
   if  (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E14') then
   begin
     //Query selecionando os campos do arquivo txt
     StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Executando a query';
     dtcompra:=StrToDate(copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,59,4));
     dtcompratxt:= FormatDateTime('dd/MM/yyyy', dtcompra);

     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tdcupant');
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE numcupom = :co2 AND ccf = :cc3 AND dtcompra = :dtc4 AND impcaixa = :ip5');
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('co2').AsString := copy(lTemp,53,6);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('cc3').AsString := copy(lTemp,47,6);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('ip5').AsString := copy(lTemp,4,20);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtc4').AsDate := StrToDate(dtcompratxt);
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;

     if not (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.IsEmpty) then
     begin
       StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Executando o loop de consulta/comparação';
         //condições para pegar o valor
         if  (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('co2').AsString)
         and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('ccf').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('cc3').AsString)
         and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('dtcompra').AsDateTime = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtc4').AsDate)
         and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('impcaixa').AsString = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('ip5').AsString)
         then
         begin
          StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Incrementando registros';
          inc(lreg);
          //Valor no BD
          valorbd := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsFloat;
          //Valor no TXT
          valortxt := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100;

          //divergências nos valores após as condições
          if (valorbd <> valortxt) then
           begin
             with DModuleGrid.ZQuery2 do
             begin
             //comparação de divergências (Identifica se sao mesmo diferentes e grava os valores no banco de dados)
               coo := copy(lTemp,53,6);
               ccf := copy(lTemp,47,6);
               ecf := copy(lTemp,4,20);
               dtc := StrToDate(dtcompratxt);
               valortxt := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100;

               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Close;
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tabc460(dtcompra, impcaixa, numcupom, ccf, valor) VALUES ( "'+DateToStr(dtc)+'", "'+ecf+'", "'+coo+'", "'+ccf+'", "'+FloatToStr(valortxt)+'")');
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ExecSQL;

               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Close;
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tabc460');
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('WHERE numcupom = :tcoo AND ccf = :tccf AND dtcompra = :tdtc AND impcaixa = :tecf AND valor = :tvalor');
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('tcoo').AsString := coo;
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('tccf').AsString := ccf;
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('tecf').AsString := ecf;
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('tdtc').AsDate := dtc;
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('tvalor').AsFloat := valortxt;
               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Open;

               DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Next;
             end;
             //incremento caso seja divergente
             inc(treg);
             //tratamento de erro
             if (valor = '') then
             begin
              valor := IntToStr(0);
             end
             else
             begin
              valor := IntToStr(treg);
             end;
           end;
         end
         else
         begin
           //caso as condições não sejam aceitas, elas sao incrementadas na variavel dc
           inc(dc);
           StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Próximo registro';
         end;
         DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Next;
     end;
   end;
 end;
  //Seleção da base depois da comparação
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tdcupant');
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;

  DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Close;
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tabc460 LIMIT 0,'+IntToStr(treg));
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Open;

  //apresenta valores divergentes nas labels
  Label1.Caption := 'Divergências '+'Valor'+' Cupons: '+valor;
  Label7.Caption := 'Divergência de cupons: '+ IntToStr(dc);
  StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text:= 'Existem '+ IntToStr(lreg) + ' linhas de Cupons(E14)';
  CloseFile(txt);
end;
```

Desculpem a falta de explicação, mas segue o que eu queria nos comentários do código.
Os `dbgrids` estão conectados aos seus respectivos `datasources`.

Isto é apenas o código feito no braço para mostrar suas funções.

Caso tenham alguma melhoria, por favor, fiquem a vontade.

Comment: @Crood, com certeza!

Comment: @Crood, OK amigo, pode deixa, vou trabalhar nas minhas perguntas. Obrigado!!

Comment: Peço que por favor aceite sua resposta se ela resolveu o problema. Assim teremos menos questões respondidas com a flag "sem resposta". Valeu!